# Regular expression to find function calls in a function body

Tags: r, regex

Please consider the body of `read.table` as a text file, created with the following code:

```
sink("readTable.txt")
body(read.table)
sink()
```

Using regular expressions, I'd like to find all function calls of the form `foo(a, b, c)` (but with any number of arguments) in `"readTable.txt"`.  That is, I'd like the result to contain the names of all called functions in the body of `read.table`. This includes nested functions of the form
 `foo(a, bar(b, c))`. Reserved words (`return`, `for`, etc) and functions that use back-ticks (`'=='()`, `'+'()`, etc) can be included since I can remove them later.

So in general, I'm looking for the pattern `text(` or `text (` then possible nested functions like `text1(text2(`, but skipping over the text **if** it's an argument, and not a function.  Here's where I'm at so far.  It's close, but not quite there.

```
x <- readLines("readTable.txt")
regx <- "^(([[:print:]]*)\\(+.*\\))"
mat <- regexpr(regx, x)
lines <- regmatches(x, mat)
fns <- gsub(".*( |(=|(<-)))", "", lines)
head(fns, 10)
# [1] "default.stringsAsFactors()" "!missing(text))"
# [3] "\"UTF-8\")" "on.exit(close(file))" "(is.character(file))"
# [6] "(nzchar(fileEncoding))" "fileEncoding)" "\"rt\")"
# [9] "on.exit(close(file))" "\"connection\"))"
```

For example, in `[9]` above, the calls are there, but I do not want `file` in the result.  Ideally it would be `on.exit(close(`.

How can I go about improving this regular expression?

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a regex solution, consider `codetools::walkCode`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872879/finding-out-which-functions-are-called-within-a-given-function/11878961#11878961

Comment: @GSee, now that is interesting, and useful. For this problem, I'd like to stick with the regex method.  This was a problem I had for an undergrad class and I'm just trying to improve upon my previous answer. Feel free to post that function as an answer though, it's pretty cool.

Comment: Can you provide sample input data your searching for as a match?

Comment: Check out the mvbutils package.

Comment: `I'd like to stick with the regex method` You can play around by adding strings to test in [this regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/oF6tD3/1) from my answer. Don't let the different colors faze you. The whole string is matched, but the color change at mid-stream indicates where Group 1 is matched (which we don't need to concern ourselves with.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've ever tried to parse HTML with a regular expression you know what a nightmare it can be. It's always better to use some HTML parser and extract info that way. I feel the same way about R code. The beauty of R is that it's functional and you inspect any function via code.

Something like

```
call.ignore <-c("[[", "[", "&","&&","|","||","==","!=",
    "-","+", "*","/", "!", ">","<", ":")

find.funcs <- function(f, descend=FALSE) {
    if( is.function(f)) {
        return(find.funcs(body(f), descend=descend))
    } else if (is(f, "name") | is.atomic(f)) {
        return(character(0))
    }
    v <- list()
    if (is(f, "call") && !(deparse(f[[1]]) %in% call.ignore)) {
        v[[1]] <- deparse(f)
        if(!descend) return(v[[1]])
    } 
    v <- append(v, lapply(as.list(f), find.funcs, descend=descend))
    unname(do.call(c, v))
}
```

could work. Here we iterate over each object in the function looking for `call`s, ignoring those you don't care about. You would run it on a function like

```
find.funcs(read.table)

# [1] "default.stringsAsFactors()"                
# [2] "missing(file)"                             
# [3] "missing(text)"                             
# [4] "textConnection(text, encoding = \"UTF-8\")"
# [5] "on.exit(close(file))"                      
# [6] "is.character(file)"  
# ...
```

You can set the `descend=` parameter to `TRUE` if you want to look in calls to functions for other functions.

I'm sure there are plenty of packages that make this easier, but I just wanted to show how simple it really is.

Comment: Can you build this out as a tree or something?  I can ask another question if need be.  If the function is multiline, it would be nice to store in a list.  The $ sign is maybe also an issue: `na.omit(github.df$links)`.  I want to build a function called `traceforward` that tracks all unique functions, possibly sorted by "library" ... using `search`

Answer (score 4):

**Recursive Regex in Perl Mode**

In the general case, I am sure you're aware of the hazards of trying to match such constructions: what if your file contains things like `if()` that you don't want to match?

That being said, I believe this recursive regex fits the requirements as I understand them

```
[a-z]+(\((?:`[()]|[^()]|(?1))*\))
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/oF6tD3/1).

I'm not completely up to scratch on `R` syntax, but something like this should work, and you can tweak the function name and arguments to suit your needs:

```
grepl("[a-z]+(\\((?:`[()]|[^()]|(?1))*\\))", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

**Explanation**

- `[a-z]+` matches the letters before the opening parenthesis
- `(` starts Group 1
- `\(` matches an opening parenthesis
- `(?:` starts a non-capture group that will be repeated. The capture group matches several possibilities:
- `BACKTICK[()]` matches a backtick + `(` or `)` (sorry, don't know how to make the backtick appear in this editor
- `|[^()]` OR match one character that is not a parenthesis
- `|(?1)` OR match the pattern defined by the Group 1 parentheses (recurse)
- `)*` close non-capture group, repeat zero or more times
- `\)` matches a closing parenthesis
- `)` ends Group 1

Comment: |(?1)   does this cover if the argument is another function call?
trying this in python using the 're' module.  complains about ?1