# Error reading in ESRI Shapefile using R

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

I'm trying to read in a shapefile using the rgdal library, and am having no luck.

When I try to import using the following syntax:

```
geo <- readOGR("/path/to/layer","layer")
```

I'm met with the error

```
Error in stopifnot(is.list(srl)) : infinite label point
```

How can I go about diagnosing and fixing the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: This question should be asked here: http://gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: can you run `ogrinfo -so /path/to/layer layer` on the command line (easiest in Linux/Mac)? The shapefile might have some infinite coordinates somehow... Check the extent output from that command.

Comment: You cross-posted here and there. Please remove one of these posts.

Comment: The extent seams reasonable: (-179.147340, 17.881242) - (179.778465, 71.390482)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Likely self-intersecting or overlapping geometries, an issue with rings/holes in the polygon Shapefile.

First off, look at the source for `readOGR`, by entering the function name without arguments in the prompt. A "find" on the source shows that the code and message in your error are not in that function.

Using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878961/483620), I found the list of functions called by `readOGR`:

```
 [1] "-"                        ":"                        "!"                        "!="                       ".Call"                   
 [6] "("                        "["                        "[["                       "{"                        "&&"                      
[11] "%in%"                     "+"                        "<"                        "<-"                       "<="                      
[16] "=="                       ">"                        "||"                       "$"                        "all.equal"               
[21] "any"                      "as.character"             "as.integer"               "as.logical"               "attr"                    
[26] "attributes"               "c"                        "cat"                      "cbind"                    "class"                   
[31] "comment"                  "CRS"                      "data.frame"               "do.call"                  "for"                     
[36] "function"                 "gc"                       "geometry"                 "getCPLConfigOption"       "getGDALVersionInfo"      
[41] "iconv"                    "identical"                "if"                       "ifelse"                   "integer"                 
[46] "is.character"             "is.na"                    "is.null"                  "isTRUE"                   "lapply"                  
[51] "length"                   "Line"                     "Lines"                    "list"                     "make.names"              
[56] "match"                    "match.arg"                "max"                      "message"                  "missing"                 
[61] "names"                    "nchar"                    "nrow"                     "ogrFIDs"                  "ogrInfo"                 
[66] "paste"                    "Polygon"                  "Polygons"                 "print"                    "rbind"                   
[71] "return"                   "rm"                       "sapply"                   "seq"                      "seq_along"               
[76] "setCPLConfigOption"       "slot"                     "sort"                     "SpatialLines"             "SpatialLinesDataFrame"   
[81] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"   "SpatialPolygons"          "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" "stop"                     "stopifnot"               
[86] "strsplit"                 "sum"                      "suppressMessages"         "switch"                   "table"                   
[91] "try"                      "unique"                   "vector"                   "warning"                  "which"
```

There are functions listed there that are actually part of `library(sp)` (you can tell because they say `<environment: namespace:sp>` when you print their source), and the error message looks like it [comes from](https://github.com/edzer/sp/blob/master/R/Class-SpatialPolygons.R#L1-L33) the `Polygon` or `Polygons` classes.

In `Polygons`, we find the code bit from the error message: `stopifnot(is.list(srl))`. Looking at `help(Polygons)`, you see that `srl` is a "list of `Polygon` class objects", so the error means that something other than a list is being passed.

So now, we should go back to the source of `readOGR` and look for calls to `Polygons` (there are three). The two first call `make_Polygonlist` (a C `rgdal` function), the third assembles its own list `pllist`. That last one is interesting, because the errors are silenced: `try(pllist[[j]] <- Polygon(cmat), silent = TRUE)`, which means this is not likely to be raising your error. That leaves the two others, and brings you to [this source code](https://github.com/cran/rgdal/blob/master/src/ogr_polygons.c#L3-L29), where we see that `makePolygonlist` is calling `make_Polygon` in the same script.

Reading there (and this is not my main language), I see a comment about:

> // hole setting based on comments by default (OGC SFS order)
>   // but by ring order if comment NULL 121019

And a bit later:

```
SET_STRING_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(dimnames, 1), 0, COPY_TO_USER_STRING("x"));
SET_STRING_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(dimnames, 1), 1, COPY_TO_USER_STRING("y"));
```

which suggests it needs x,y coordinates of some sort in order to handle holes / rings in polygons. Back to `help("Polygons-class")` we see a parameter `labpt` which is:

> Object of class "numeric"; pair of x, y coordinates giving a label
>   point, the label point of the largest ring component

And now we can give a hypothesis about he cause of the error: it is related to the handling of rings/holes in polygons, and while creating the `Polygon` objects, it needs label points to correctly handle the rings/holes. However, the label points it finds are not finite, and the error is triggered.

And finally, there is a note:

> Polygon objects belonging to an Polygons object should either not
>   overlap one-other, or should be fully included (as lakes or islands in
>   lakes). They should not be self-intersecting.

which suggests that you are likely having issues with a bad geometry, which is overlapping or self-intersecting. You can use tools (for example in QGis) to check and fix the geometry.