# How to get the list of in-built functions used within a function

Tags: r, function

Lets say I have a function named `Fun1` within which I am using many different in-built functions of R for different different processes. Then how can I get a list of in-built functions used inside this function `Fun1`

```
  Fun1 <- function(x,y){
  sum(x,y)
  mean(x,y)
  c(x,y)
  print(x)
  print(y)
  }
```

So My output should be like list of characters i.e. `sum`, `mean`, `c`, `print`. Because these are the in-built functions I have used inside function `Fun1`.

I have tried using `grep` function

```
 grep("\\(",body(Fun1),value=TRUE)
 # [1] "sum(x, y)"  "mean(x, y)" "c(x, y)"    "print(x)"   "print(y)"
```

It looks ok, but arguments should not come i.e. `x` and `y`. Just the list of function names used inside body of function `Fun1` here.

So my overall goal is to print the `unique list of in-built functions or any create functions inside a particular function`, here `Fun1`.

Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I imagine one would have to use string matching to do such a task (`grep`). e.g. `select %>% body() %>% toString()`. You are also going to want a list of the functions you are searching for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding out which functions are called within a given function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872879/finding-out-which-functions-are-called-within-a-given-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `all.vars()` to get all the variable names (including functions) that appear inside the body of `Fun1`, then compare that with some prepared list of functions.  You mention in-built functions, so I will compare it with the base package object names.

```
## full list of variable names inside the function body
(vars <- all.vars(body(Fun1)[-1], functions = TRUE))
# [1] "sum"   "x"     "y"     "mean"  "c"     "print"

## compare it with the base package object names
intersect(vars, ls(baseenv()))
# [1] "sum"   "mean"  "c"     "print"
```

I removed the first element of the function body because presumably you don't care about `{`, which would have been matched against the base package list.

Another possibility, albeit a bit less reliable, would be to compare the formal arguments of `Fun1` to all the variable names in the function. Like I said, likely less reliable though because if you make assignments inside the function you will end up with incorrect results.

```
setdiff(vars, names(formals(Fun1)))
# [1] "sum"   "mean"  "c"     "print"
```

These are fun though, and you can fiddle around with them.

Comment: please also include `setdiff` command too, and also how it is different from `intersect` I understand intersect command.

Comment: I will.  Bare with me, it's 1:15 am here :)

Comment: Also, any idea on what if I created a custom function inside a function, even that would come using `setdiff` right? but it wont show up when I `intersect` it with `base` package because it is my custom function.

Answer (score 5):

Access to the parser tokens is available with functions from `utils`.

```
tokens <- utils::getParseData(parse(text=deparse(body(Fun1))))
unique(tokens[tokens[["token"]] == "SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL", "text"])
[1] "sum"   "mean"  "c"     "print"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be somewhat helpful - this will return all functions however.

```
func_list = Fun1 %>% 
  body() %>% # extracts function
  toString() %>% # converts to single string
  gsub("[{}]", "", .)  %>% # removes curly braces
  gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)", "", .) %>% # removes all contents between brackets
  strsplit(",") %>% # splits strings at commas
  unlist() %>% # converts to vector
  trimws(., "both") # removes all white spaces before and after`
```

`[1] ""      "sum"   "mean"  "c"     "print" "print"`

```
> table(func_list)
func_list
          c  mean print   sum 
    1     1     1     2     1
```

This is extremely limited to your example... you could modify this to be more robust. It will fall over where a function has brackets nesting other functions etc.

Comment: This would a good version by using `dplyr`. Thank you. This one too helped. I also wanted the basic version. I have reduced code to two steps.

Comment: I also liked when you did use `table()`.

Answer (score 1):

this is not so beautiful but working:

```
Fun1 <- function(x,y){
    sum(x,y)
    mean(x,y)
    c(x,y)
    print(x)
    print(y)
}


getFNamesInFunction <- function(f.name){
    f <- deparse(body(get(f.name)))
    f <- f[grepl(pattern = "\\(", x = f)]
    f <- sapply(X = strsplit(split = "\\(", x = f), FUN = function(x) x[1])
    unique(trimws(f[f != ""]))
}
getFNamesInFunction("Fun1")
[1] "sum"   "mean"  "c"     "print"
```

Comment: Wow, it works. One question why your `f.name` should be provided in quotes.

Comment: i decided it will be better to pass function name rather then the function itself.

Comment: No I mean how I would know that I have to provide the argument in quotes and not without quotes, or else there should be something inside the function to convert argument name to character.

Comment: You could improve this by making it take only the first word before brackets. getFNamesInFunction("apply") will return an example of why.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me what is that `x[1]` at the end of sapply?

Comment: it takes the first arg of the split

Comment: you can modify getFNamesInFunction to handle both input types "closure" and "character" by checking typeof() at the start

Comment: no, it is part of the sapply. made for getting first arguments after the split

Comment: You mean `typeof(Fun1)`?

Comment: Yes I got that `FUN` is part of sapply.

Answer (score 0):

```
as.list(Fun1)[3]
```

gives you the part of the function between the curly braces.

```
{
    sum(x, y)
    mean(x, y)
    c(x, y)
    print(x)
    print(y)
}
```

Hence

```
 gsub( ").*$", "", as.list(Fun1)[3])
```

gives you everything before the first " `)` " appears which is presumable the name of the first function.

Taking this as a starting point you should be able to include a loop which gives you the other functions and not the first only the first one.

Comment: `gsub` is not working in your answer. I have edited my `grep` part now I am getting the output posted above. Just need to print text before `(` also, if any function is repeating I do not want them to be repeated in the output.

Comment: the gsub is not working. Dont know why. I tried thrice. May be tehre is some problem in the pattern you provided to gsub?

Comment: On my console (RStudio, R 3.3.0) gsub is working. However if I implement some minor changes such as `(` instead of `)` i get the following error **Error in gsub("(.*$", "", as.list(Fun1)[3]) : 
  invalid regular expression '(.*$', reason 'Missing ')''**