# Check whether certain function is used inside a nested function in R

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function `check_sym` that takes another function `f` as argument and checks whether inside `f` a specific function is used.

Specifically I want to check if inside `f` non-standard evaluation in the form of `!! sym` is used.

I can do this with a simple trick that turns a functions body into a character string and then uses regex to check for `"!!sym\\("`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

check_sym <- function(f) {
  f <- as.list(body(f))
  f <- unlist(as.character(f))
  purrr::some(f, function(x) grepl("!!sym\\(", x))
}

foo <- function(df, x) { 
  select(df, !! sym(x))
}

check_sym(foo)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, while this is possible, I am looking for a way that does not rely on character strings and regex, but rather ideally some method which looks inside the function and "sees" all function calls at a deeper level, which would be more reliable.

Any ideas appreciated.

**Final solution based on accepted answer:**

Based on MrFlick's answer below my actual solution is the following:

I define check_syms as:

```r
check_sym <- function(f) {
  grepl("!!sym", paste(all.names(body(f)), collapse = ""))
}
```

It correctly identifies functions which make a function call to `"!! sym"` compared to functions that only call for example `paste0("!!sym")`.

```r
foo <- function(df, x) { 
  select(df, !! sym(x))
}

test_f <- function(x) {
  print(paste0("!!sym", x))
}

check_sym(foo)
#> [1] TRUE

check_sym(test_f)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Are you looking for both `!!` and `sym`

Comment: Both would be ideal, yes.

Comment: But if there is a nice & easy way to do it with `sym` alone, I would be more than happy to see it.

Comment: You may convert some of the steps in your own function to single one i.e. `any(grepl('sym', capture.output(body(f))))`

Comment: `check_sym <- function(f)  any(grepl('sym', capture.output(body(f))))#
> check_sym(foo)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: That even saves my call to `purrr::some`. Nice.

Comment: See also this possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872879/finding-out-which-functions-are-called-within-a-given-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `all.names` function. It pulls out the names of all the variables/function defined inside the function

```
all.names(body(foo))
# [1] "{"      "select" "df"     "!"      "!"      "sym"   
# [7] "x"
```

Part of the problem with your specific example is that `!!sym` isn't really a simple variable. It's more like a call to `!(!(sym))` to the parser. The `!!` stuff really isn't a special operator to the R parser, it's just two calls to the negation operator which rlang re-interprets via non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Thanks! This is more or less what I was looking for. Applying a regex on the output of `all.names` ensures that actually a function with this name was called.

Answer (score 5):

In `base R`, we can capture the output of `body` into a vector of strings and use `grepl`

```
check_sym <- function(f)  any(grepl('!!sym(', capture.output(body(f)), fixed = TRUE))

check_sym(foo)
# [1] TRUE 


some_fct <- function(x) print("sym")
check_sym(some_fct)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It only uses `base` R and is much less verbose. However, it still relies on regex and cannot "see" the difference between a real function call to `sym()` and the string `"sym"`. So this function `some_fct <- function(x) print("sym")` would also evaluate to `TRUE`.

Comment: @TimTeaFan updated the post, but not sure whether there are conditions that cause it to. fail