# R which function runs another function

Tags: r, function

I have code like this:

```
f.internal <- function(){
  print("f.internal was called by ...")
}

f.external <- function(){
  f.internal()
}
```

How to check in R, which of the two functions runs the other function?

Comment: Relevant / Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143110/visualizing-r-function-dependencies

Comment: Another related link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795982/generating-a-call-graph-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a helper named getCaller(), which uses stop() within a tryCatch to generate a [traceback](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/traceback.html) call stack. Using that it can identify the last few calling functions.

Then have f.internal() call the helper to produce the desired output.