# How to tell what functions are called by a function? Like traceback() with no error needed?

Tags: r, debugging

Is there a function or debugger in R to show what functions were called by a function? i.e., it would function a bit like `traceback` but triggered by a call to function instead of an error, and showing not just the stack but the tree of function calls. Like:

```
A-> B -> C -> D
    E -> F
    G -> C -> D
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but the following might be useful: [Generating a call graph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795982/generating-a-call-graph-in-r) and [Finding out which functions are called within a given function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872879/finding-out-which-functions-are-called-within-a-given-function)

Comment: Edit : I think this may be a duplicate too.

Comment: My first thought was profiling, which might be overkill for what you want ... but then again, conditional branches in code make call-graphs context-specific, so profiling with a spread of parameters will eventually show a bigger picture (if not the "whole picture").

Comment: thanks - I agree those questions (I didn't use the term call-graph) will generate the answer I am looking for

Comment: Are we happy to close this as duplicate, Tim?

Comment: Yes: let's close as dup